# How to fetch more than 50 items when executing nexus rest api get request

Tags: groovy, get, nexus

we have a corporate remote nexus repository.i want a groovy (which will be added to jenkins)script  get the paths of all the directories and subdirectories and put into a list and return the list.Based on the selection of path with jenkins choise parameter i want to list all the zip files form the seclected path and the selected zip file will be used when the jenkins job runs.

My jenkins job selction

[image: jenkins active choise parameter selection]

so first to get all the directories and subdirectories path i wrote a groovy scrip which sends a rest api get requrest to my nexus repository

```
def requestUrl = "${nexusbaseUrl}/service/rest/v1/search?repository=<myreponame>&group=/<myGroupName>/*"
def response = "curl -X GET $requestUrl".execute().text
```

then i am parsing the response and adding value of the key called "group" to a from the response . the value will be path to directory.

**now the issue is nexus get api  returns only 50 items/components with continuation token at the end . I know from Nexus sonetype documentation we can add this token at the end of request url to get next 50 data but as my data is very large i cant afford to make many requests and this will take more time.**

My remote repo structure

```
|-myGroupName
    |--project1
    |--project2
          |-sub1
          |-sub2
          |-sub3
             |-v1.0
             |-v2.0
                 |-2024-1-3
                 |-2024-1-5
                     |-bbc.zip
             |-v3.0
          |-sub4
      |--project3
```

My rest api response

```
    {
  "items" : [ {
    "id" : "some data",
    "repository" : "some data",
    "format" : "raw",
    "group" : "/myGroupName/project2/sub3/v2.0/2024-1-5/",
    "name" : "/myGroupName/project2/sub3/v2.0/2024-1-5/bbc.zip",
    "version" : "some data",
    "assets" : [ {
      "downloadUrl" : "",
      "path" : "/myGroupName/project2/sub3/v2.0/2024-1-5/bbc.zip",
      "id" : "some data",
      "repository" : "myreponame",
      "format" : "raw",
      "checksum" : {
        "sha1" : "some data",
        "md5" : "some data"
      },
      "contentType" : "application/zip",
      "lastModified" : "some data",
      "lastDownloaded" : "some data",
      "uploader" : "some data",
      "uploaderIp" : "some data",
      "fileSize" : 0
    } ],
    "tags" : [ ]
  }, {49 other items} ],
  "continuationToken" : "938580409939430"
}
```

some data here is confidential information. As I said I am using this continuation token to fetch next 50 data and so on...

My groovy code

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1')
 
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
 
def getFilesRecursive(String baseUrl) {
    def fileSet = new HashSet<>() // Using Set to ensure unique entries
    def continuationToken = null
 
    do {
        def response = makeGetRequest(baseUrl, continuationToken)
        def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
 
        json.items.each { item ->
            fileSet.add(item.group) // Adding path to the set
        }
 
        continuationToken = json.continuationToken
    } while (continuationToken)
 
    return fileSet as List // Converting Set to List before returning
}
 
def makeGetRequest(String url, String continuationToken = null) {

    def tokenParam = continuationToken ? "&continuationToken=${continuationToken}" : ""
    def requestUrl = "${url}${tokenParam}"
    println "requesturl is " + requestUrl
    def response = "curl -X GET $requestUrl".execute().text
    return response
}
 
def main() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() // Record start time
    def nexusbaseUrl = 'https://<myBaseurl>'
    def requestUrl = "${nexusbaseUrl}/service/rest/v1/search?repository=<myreponame>&group=/<myGroupName>/*"
 
    def fileList = getFilesRecursive(requestUrl)
 
    println "List of files:"
    fileList.each { println it }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() // Record end time
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime
    println "total time in sec: " + totalTime/1000
    
}
 
main()
```

**is there a way to get more than 50 items (say 1000) items with one get request or is there a better way to get path to all the directories of remote nexus server recursively and add them to a list. (groovy script is appreciated) ??**